# No `read_json_lines_files()` function for `OutputFileDatasetConfig`

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I have a pipeline step which produces image labels like the one exported from a `Data Labeling` project which is a `jsonl` file.

This step produces the `jsonl` label file in a `OutputFileDatasetConfig` and then I think I would do

```py
output_file_dataset_config.read_json_lines_files().register_on_complete("foo")
```

but this magical `read_json_lines_files()` function does not exists.

How can I achieve the same behavior with then currently available API?

Comment: would also be worth including the version of the `azureml-sdk` that you're on

Answer (score 1):

that is weird! especially because the [OutputDatasetConfig docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.outputfiledatasetconfig?view=azure-ml-py) give an example where they do something very similar! I suggest opening a priority support ticket if possible.

```py
output = OutputFileDatasetConfig().read_delimited_files().register_on_complete('foo')
```